# Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined in angular 2

Tags: html, angular

I am validating my template using angular2, but meanwhile it shows this error:

```
 Cannot read the property 'errors' of undefined.
```

Here is my template:

```
<h3 class = "head">{{title}}</h3>
<form  [ngFormModel]="form" #f="ngForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">     
      <label class="formHeading">Facebook</label>
      <input type="text" id="facebook" class="form-control col-xs-3"  ngControl="facebook" #facebook="ngForm" >  
    </div>
    <div *ngIf ="facebook.touched  && facebok.errors">  
      <div class="form-row btn">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right butspace" [disabled]="!f.valid">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I dont know why it shows this error. Can anyone fix it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all, you have `facebok` instead of `facebook` on the error property.

If that doesn't fix it you're probably using the `facebook` object before it is assigned, which can happen if it's an `@Input()` for example.

Use the `Elvis operator`:

```
*ngIf ="facebook?.touched && facebook?.errors"
```

Comment: Elvis operator worked for me. I was setting up my form groups in the constructor, which was apparently too late for the DOM.

Comment: @hholtij I couldn't post the full comment here, so I answered the post.